# Использование currentTarget?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
 <table> 
    <tr> 
     <td class="one">01</td > 
     <td class="two">02</td>
        <td class="three">03</td> 
     </tr > 
    <tr > 
        <td class="one">11</td>
        <td class="two">12</td>
        <td class="three">13</td> 
     </tr > 
    <tr >
        <td class="one">21</td> 
        <td class="two">22</td>
        <td class="three">23</td>
      </tr > 
    </table >
```

Суть: при клике по любому `td` получать значение первого `td` в данной строке `tr`. 
Например: пользователь кликает по

```
  <td class="three">23</td>
```

И мы получаем в переменную `21`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    td_first = $('td:first', tr).text();
    $('#result').html(td_first);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">01</td>
    <td class="two">02</td>
    <td class="three">03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">11</td>
    <td class="two">12</td>
    <td class="three">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">21</td>
    <td class="two">22</td>
    <td class="three">23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
td = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); //получаем все ячейки
for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) td[i].addEventListener('click', ClickTD, false); //привязываем к ячейкам наше событие

function ClickTD(e){ //е - событие, которое вызвало функцию, target - цель (элемент который вызвал событие), parentNode - родитель нашего элемента, children[0] - первый элемент в родителе
 alert(e.target.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `addEventListener` в цикле - это нехорошо.